# meson finds python3 binary, fails to find python3 dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, pkg-config, meson-build

I'm trying to build a certain repository using meson on Cygwin. This is what happens:

```
$ meson build_dir
The Meson build system
Version: 0.58.2
Source dir: /home/joeuser/src/meld-3.21.0
Build dir: /home/joeuser/src/meld-3.21.0/build_dir
Build type: native build
Project name: meld
Project version: 3.21.0
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.6.3)
Run-time dependency python3 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and sysconfig)

meson.build:18:0: ERROR: Dependency "python3" not found, tried pkgconfig and sysconfig
```

Why is this happening? And how can I get meson to find the python3 dependency?

Note: I've installed `python38-pkgconfig` in case that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meson will find python3 if you also install the `python3-devel` package using the Cygwin installer.

Comment: Exactly, python3 is a binary, but most linux distros (and cygwin) package development headers separately.

Comment: @dcbaker: Well, I would have assumed that since python3 isn't a library, it wouldn't have a "-devel" version - but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Python is both a library and a program. When you build a python extension with C or C++, you include the python headers and (sometimes) link against libpython.

Comment: can you share the mac terminal command to install python3-devel? I am unable to find it

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu: I wasn't talking about macs... :-(

Comment: I missed that when I read this. I am trying to build meld on my mac m2 since the downloaded dmgs are not working. I am stuck at the same point... unfortunately I don't know how to proceed. If you have any insights, please let me know

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu I've never used Macs, and almost never used FreeBSD. So... not really. I suggest you ask a new question, but just remember to clearly state what you tried and what errors you're getting. And maybe link to it from here...